# CoInitializeSecurity failed on disabling clr option

Tags: c++, com, clr, managed

I have an application which is written in managed code and runs sucessfully, however now i disabled the /clr option from visual studio 2008 and made necessary changes to remove the manages code and convert it to native, and successfully compiled the code, however, the function `CoInitializeSecurity()` is failing with `HResult = 0x800401f0`.
Saying `CoInitialize has not been called....`
When i say `GetLastError()` it `returns 0`.

```
HRESULT hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
                                NULL,
                                -1,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
                                RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
                                NULL,
                                EOAC_NONE,
                                NULL
                                );
if (FAILED(hres))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "COM Init failed...", "Stop", MB_OK);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Thanks in advance,,

The same code works fine if /clr enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The same code works fine if /clr enabled

Sure.  It was the CLR that took care of calling CoInitializeEx() before.  Picking the apartment type from the [STAThread] attribute on the Main() entrypoint or the value you passed to Thread::SetApartmentState(), if any.  Default is MTA.

That's not happening anymore since you now compile without /clr.  You therefore must call CoInitializeEx() yourself.